# Disable automatic doubling of quotes in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, quotes

Notepad++ automatically places another quote if I type a single quote or double quote. How can I disable this?

Comment: Thanks! It's such an annoying "feature".

Comment: This is not what smart quotes are. “Smart quotes” are those annoying curly quotes that, for example, MS Word replaces regular quotes with to show you how smart MS programmers are.

Comment: I changed the title, because [Smart Quotes](https://smartquotesforsmartpeople.com/ "Smart Quotes for Smart People") is another topic.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Notepad++ has a setting that controls the auto-completion behavior.

```
Settings -> Preferences -> Auto-Completion ->Auto-Insert
```

**Edit:**

Your requirement:

> We need to type quotes twice for them to appear and when they do appear, there are two of them.

This behavior is controlled by Keyboard language settings in Control Panel. Go to

```
Control Panel -> Regional and Language -> Keyboards and Languages
```

and select a keyboard language which requires typing twice before quotes appear.

Comment: Not what we are looking for. We need to type quotes twice for them to appear and when they do appear, there are two of them.

Comment: i don't know if such setting exists in NP++, deduced from [some source](http://bytes.com/topic/windows/answers/914227-have-type-single-double-quotes-twice), this might be controlled by the regional setting in Control Panel - try to set it as some language other than United States.

Comment: Yeah. I don't believe the maker of any software program would want to do that. And yes you are right. It's caused by a keyboard called United States International. Thanks for your help. 

If you add this as an answer, I'll choose it as the correct answer.

Comment: For peeps who don't want this 'smart' feature of having to double type for the quotes to appear - Go to your control panel -> language and remove international from the US language options

Answer (score 2):

You may have two issues going on - the keyboard setting causing you to have to enter it twice, and/or the settings issue in Notepad++.

For those ONLY seeing this problem in Notepadd++, it is under Settings-->Auto-Completion "Auto-Insert" (box, midscreen,) and check or uncheck the box by " ".